# Cannot access my web page from a different machine - within same WIFI

Tags: tomcat, web-applications

I have a simple web application running in tomcat-7 server in my system. When I try to access the link say - `"http://localhost:8182/<my-app>/<my-page>"` through the my system browser, it works fine(I mean it has to work fine :)). Also when I access using my IP address instead of localhost, it works fine. However, if I access the same link with my IP address in another system which is connected to same WIFI, It gives me a message saying - "Page cannot be displayed". I donot know how to solve this issue. Suggestions Please..
(If the details provided are not enough, please let me know)

Comment: can you telnet the port: `telnet MyIPAddress 8182` ? what's the result?

Comment: when i do the telnet i get a blank cmd prompt

Answer (score 0):

1. check you are using the right IP address, 127.0.0.1 is the same as
   local host and only works on the local machine. If you are also
   connected to more than one network (e.g. wired, WIFI, VPN tunnel),
   you may have two IP addresses one of which is not visible locally
2. Check your firewall is configured to allow connections on the server machine, also check the routing rules on your WIFI router to
   ensure that machines are permitted to connect to each other.

Comment: When you say 2 ip addresses, u mean one is system and other is public right? If so, I have tried with both and no luck with it.                I think I'll have to check on the rules of Wifi router